# Setting SetFieldValueByValueCollection CSOM and C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I seem to be struggling to set multiple values into `SetFieldValueByValueCollection` Method.

My code snippet below is:

```
var fieldToUpdate = list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Enterprise Keywords"); 
var taxKeywordField = context.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(fieldToUpdate);

string fieldvalue = "-1;#Test|dfb5ae8e-6271-4b27-86ea-0ff04a3292b0;-1;#TestAdditional|b9033830-9f74-4e1d-baaa-7711beeed141";
taxKeywordField.SetFieldValueByValueCollection(uploadFile.ListItemAllFields, new TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(context, fieldvalue, taxKeywordField));
taxKeywordField.Update();
uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();

context.Load(uploadFile.ListItemAllFields);
context.ExecuteQueryRetry();
```

The error I recieve back is:

> *The given value for a taxonomy field was not formatted in the required < int > ; # < label >| format.*

If I pass 1 parameter in `-1;#Test|dfb5ae8e-6271-4b27-86ea-0ff04a3292b0` it works. I have tried varying the input string to `-1;#Test|dfb5ae8e-6271-4b27-86ea-0ff04a3292b0;#TestAdditional|b9033830-9f74-4e1d-baaa-7711beeed141` and tried to run multiple updates on the field which overrides the field with the last term.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you try with `-1;#Test|dfb5ae8e-6271-4b27-86ea-0ff04a3292b0;#-1;#TestAdditional|b9033830-9f74-4e1d-baaa-7711beeed141` ?

Comment: Thanks. 100% correct. Was missing the #. Just overlooked it, somehow, in all the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are setting the delimiter incorrectly.

The correct format is `"<int>;#<label>|<guid>` with `;#` delimiter between the terms.

So modifying your string to

`-1;#Test|dfb5ae8e-6271-4b27-86ea-0ff04a3292b0;#-1;#TestAdditional|b9033830-9f74-4e1d-baaa-7711beeed141` should work.

Comment: Thank you. Something so small I just kept on missing.